# labels for Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, categories, drive

Use case: Just like in Blogs we have Categories and Tags to filter content using 2 separate lists. I need to use Google Drive files to store and filter files differently.

Folder structure is one way to organize files. Labels would have been the other. 
How do I implement Labels OR are there alternatives for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:-

1. Use folders. In Drive, folders actually behave like labels rather than as containers. They used to be called Collections before being renamed to Folders a few years ago.
2. Use properties. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties
3. Use the Description field.

Each has its own pros and cons, and it comes down to your specific use case as to which is the better option. As a quick pointer, option 1 works best if you intend users to be able to manipulate labels from drive.google.com as well as in your app. Option 3 has the advantage that labels will show up in a search.